# Publishing element in 3DExperience 2018 with VBA

Tags: vba, catia

Is there a way to publish element with VBA in 3DX 2018? I tried to use SimPublicationService object of ActiveEditor, but as I do not have any Simulia role this object is unavailable to me. Is there another way to publish element with VBA without using this service?

Comment: How do you envision a 3D modeling object to "have" VBA? Or do you mean something other than Visual Basic for Applications when you say VBA?

Comment: Well as I understand it, by using CATIA.ActiveEditor.GetService "SimPublicationService" method I can gain an access to certain functions of CATIA application. By manipulating object which is assigned to it I can for instance publish 3D elements. And yes, I ment Visual Basic for Applications.